# POST запрос в андроид

Tags: java, android, post

в gradle прописано:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5'
```

в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Не могу получить данные.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost http = new HttpPost(myURL);
            List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", loginMap.get(0)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", loginMap.get(1)));
            try {
                http.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                String response = (String) httpclient.execute(http, new BasicResponseHandler());
                System.out.println(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Вываливается ошибка:

```
12-26 12:31:49.114 13673-13673/com.lovelinux.root.tmaxim E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lovelinux.root.tmaxim, PID: 13673
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:658)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:632)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:621)
   at com.lovelinux.root.tmaxim.MainActivity$1$override.onClick(MainActivity.java:94)
   at com.lovelinux.root.tmaxim.MainActivity$1$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
   at com.lovelinux.root.tmaxim.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:0)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

---

```
class httpQUERY extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String myURL = "https://адрес";
    String params ;
    byte[] data = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... paramss) {
        if (!loginMap.isEmpty()) {
            params = "login=" + loginMap.get(0) + "&password=" + loginMap.get(1);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Empty array");
            return null;
        }
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost http = new HttpPost(myURL);
        List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", loginMap.get(0)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", loginMap.get(1)));
        try {
            http.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String response = (String) httpclient.execute(http, new BasicResponseHandler());
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {//Выполняется после doInBackground
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("I am here");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` свидетельствует о том, что Вы пытаетесь обратиться к веб-ресурсу из UI-потока, чего делать нельзя.

Все запросы к интернету нужно осуществлять в потоках, отличных от UI-потока. В самом примитивном случае можно использовать `AsyncTask`, но, вообще говоря, лучше использовать библиотеки, которые *из коробки* могут выполнять запросы не в UI-потоке (OkHttp, RoboSpice и т.п.).

**UPD:** Если Вы получаете данное исключение и используете `AsyncTask`, то проверьте, не вызываете ли Вы напрямую метод `doInBackground(...)`, если вызываете – замените строку вызова этого метода на `task.execute(...)`, где `task` – экземпляр класса `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Вот тут у меня выполняется
`class httpQUERY extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        
    }`

Comment: @Ghost, Покажите полный код класса, в котором вызывается асинстаск и укажите строку, на которой приложение падает.

Comment: String response = (String) httpclient.execute(http, new BasicResponseHandler());

Comment: Код выложен выше

Comment: @Ghost, `Покажите полный код класса, в котором вызывается асинстаск`. И еще: посмотрите **UPD** в ответе.

Comment: Выложено под логами

Comment: @Ghost, Я просил другой код. Как Вы запускаете асинстаск?

Comment: `public void onclick(View v) {
mt = new httpQUERY();
mt.doInBackground();
}`

Comment: @Ghost, Посмотрите **UPD** к ответу.